# Facebook work history fql

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

I am creating facebook application where in user will be able to fetch the company name of all the friends in friends list

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) { 
    var query = FB.Data.query('select name,work,work_history,pic_square 
       from user where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1={0})', response.id) 
    query.wait(function(rows){ 
      var data = ""; 
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length;i++) { 
         data += rows[i].name + " => " +'<img src="' +rows[i].pic_square + '" alt="image" />' + "===> "; 
         if(rows[i].work[i]||rows[i].work_history[i]) { 
             data+=rows[i].work_history[0].company_name+ "<br/>"; 
         } 
         data += "<br />";
       } 
       document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = data; 
     }); 
   }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/561/

FB.Data.query was deprecated a very long time ago. Here's an example of how to achieve the same goal: http://www.fbrell.com/saved/b9b65bf81dc84b58fc1e167167b13112 (Note it only uses `work_history`, take a look at `work` too.

A few things to consider:

- When you have JS strings spreading on more rows, make sure you concatenate as in the example I included, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches.
- Why check rows[i].work[i]? i contains the value of the index of the current friend. Work and work_history are arrays of my previous jobs, you should check the length of the array and make sure it's > 0.

Comment: Thank you so much :) minor mistakes i did . Thanks for helping out.You saved my time